# Laravel authentication by session, different domains, same application

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-sanctum, laravel-authentication, laravel-octane

In my new Project, I need to create an authentication system, the requirements are:

1. authentication should be done for different domains and sub-domains
2. for now, the only client type is front-end applications(SPA)
3. site A can have two domains, `company.my-domain.com` and a custom domain for itself like: `company.com`

the first thing that came to my mind was to use stateless authentication by `JWT tokens`, but I couldn't think of a way to securely store JWT in the front-end, storage is vulnerable to `XSS`, and `CSRF` for cookies should be considered.
laravel sanctum stateless authentication is not using the cookies and sessions, that's why I don't think for this app stateless authentication is a good choice.

the second way and stateful way was to use the `cookies`, which is supported by sanctum by default, but the problem is I cannot use cookies for different domains, so I have to point different domains to my server and create virtual hosts, so that :

- `company.my-domain.com` sends its requests to the `api.my-domain.com` (cause cookies can be shared between subdomains)
- `company.com` sends its requests to the `api.company.com` (cause `api.my-domain.com` cannot set cookies for another domain)

the problem is, laravel is using an environment variable called `SESSION_DOMAIN`, and you can only set it once, I can't and don't want to launch a new instance with different env variables for each custom domain, so my question is:

how to set the session domain environment variables dynamically? and does the fact that I'm using octane will affect other requests in this case? because I used `Config::set()`,
it does affect the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` but not any of the sanctum cookie domains

any help and recommendation would be appreciated!

Comment: @N69S hello there, what do you mean by off-topic exactly? did you bother reading all the question text???

Comment: I did, but you didnt bother reading the [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) post. Your question is seeking recommandation, and is opinion based. SO is for code, you should post this kind of questions on meta. Also, JWT is a temporary access, which make it as secure as cookies+csrf. Also, using JWT from another place is not considered XSS attack since it's another place.

Comment: @N69S Please don't suggest posting questions like this on Meta.  It would be [wildly off-topic there](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: @RyanM my bad, will do.